How to Run a Python File on a Specific Virtual Desktop Only?
I want to run a Python script and have it perform actions on a specific virtual desktop without affecting other desktops.
Currently, when I execute my Python file using VS Code, functions like webbrowser.open() and PyAutoGUI keyboard and mouse commands operate on the desktop where I’m currently working, rather than the one where I initially started the program.

Do you mean open a new browser window (firefox, chrome, ...) rather than a new tab into an existing window ?

No, I want all actions in the script to be performed exclusively on a specific virtual desktop.

what system do you use?

I use Windows 11
